# tfs 2017 build multiple solutions dependency

Tags: tfs, build, build-definition

How to create build definition for multiple solutions that have dependency?

Background here:

There are two solutions

Solution A is class library contains an object class 'ClassA'

Solution B is console program that use 'ClassA' by add dll reference generated by solution A.

I would like to server build both solutions using one TFS 2017 build definition.

It raise out error:

```
   Main\Source\SolutionB\Program.cs (13, 13)
   Main\Source\SolutionB\SolutionB\Program.cs(13,13): Error CS0246:
   The type or namespace name 'SolutionA' could not be found (are you 
   missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)
```

How to config the build definition that SolutionB would know to use the dll generated from the build of SolutionA?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should build your first project that will be used at second project as dll and than copy files to build artifacts; than publish your dlls to specific folder that you  referenced in your second project and finally build your second project.

You can check this image that with similiar process, just in below image it is publishing artifacts to three diffrent location, in your case it should be one publish task.
[image]

This is one of the simple way; but if you use the project A for some other projects too you may want to use NuGet packages. I am going to describe this as solution 2.

**Solution 2:** You should [create a Nuget packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/create-packages/creating-a-package) by the artifacts of Project A. You can [host your  Nuget packages](https://learn.microsoft.com/tr-tr/nuget/hosting-packages/overview) in custom source folder. Add your first project's package to your project as a reference. You don't need to do something extra just add a nuget restore task to your build definition. If you want, you can publish your first project as a nuget package during the build definiton. Please check  [how to restore and install neuget packages by build definiton](https://www.visualstudio.com/en-us/docs/package/build/team-build-nuget).

Comment: What you're describing is a terrible practice. Binary dependencies should be managed as NuGet packages.

Comment: @DanielMann this is one of the simple way to solve this problem and it seems it is working, for my persperctive a bad solution that working is better than nothing; on the other hand yes you are right managing by nuget packages is better. I am going to edit my answer and add this solution too. thanks.